# bootstrap form validation only one field required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that has userID and screen name input fields.

When validating I need to make sure that at least one of them is entered (if both were entered I only take one). The html:

```js
this.addFormValidators = function () {


$('#editCreatePipeForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            ConsumerKey: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Consumer Key is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            ConsumerKeySecret: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Consumer Key Secret is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            CollectionIntervalSec: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The collection interval is required'
                    },
                    between: {
                        message: 'The collection interval must be a number greater than 10',
                        min: 10,
                        max: 1000000000
                    }
                }
            },
            //KeepHistoricalDataTimeSec: {
            //    validators: {
            //        notEmpty: {
            //            message: 'The retain data value is required'
            //        },
            //        between: {
            //            message: 'The retain data value must be a number greater than 1000',
            //            min: 1000,
            //            max: 1000000000
            //        }
            //    }
            //},
            Description: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 500,
                        message: 'The description must be less than 500 characters long'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, null);
};
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ScreenName" class="col-md-4 YcdFormLabel" title="screen name of user to retrieve">Screen name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Screen Name" class="form-control user" autocomplete="off"
                   name="screenName"
                   id="screenName" data-bind="value: screenName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"/>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            @*<div class="col-md-8">*@
            <label for="or" class="col-md-10">or</label>

            @*</div>*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userID" class="col-md-4 YcdFormLabel" title="user_ID of user to retrieve">User ID</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" placeholder="User ID" class="form-control user" autocomplete="off"
                   name="userID"
                   id="userID" data-bind="value: userID, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another function which I called it before submitting instead of using Bootstrap and jQuery form validation.

```
private hasTimelineAndUsername = (): boolean => {
    if (this.viewModel.searchSelection() == "timeline"
        && ((this.viewModel.userID() == "" ||
            this.viewModel.userID() == null) &&
            (this.viewModel.screenName() == "" ||
                this.viewModel.screenName() == null))) {
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

The submitting function:

```
public getCollectionParameters() {
    var fv = $('#editCreatePipeForm').data('formValidation')
    fv.validate();
    var isValid = fv.isValid();
    if (!isValid) {
        toastr.error("Please fix all problems before saving");
        return null;
    }
    if (!this.hasTimelineAndUsername()) {
        toastr.clear();
        toastr.error("Please type username/userID");
        return null;
    }
    if (!this.validateData()) {
        return null;
    }

    return JSON.stringify(ko.mapping.toJS(this.viewModel));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope my code will help you.

- **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/aice09/3wjdvf30/
- **CodePen**: https://codepen.io/aice09/pen/XgQyem
- **GitHub**: https://github.com/Ailyn09/project102/blob/master/chooseintwoinput.html

```js
function verify() {
    var screenName = document.getElementById("screenName").value;
    var userID = document.getElementById("userID").value;

    if (userID === '' && screenName === '') {
        alert('Add value to any field');
    }
    if (userID !== '' && screenName === '') {
        alert('Your screen name are currently empty. The value you will be taken is your screen name');
        document.getElementById("takedvalue").value = userID;
    }
    if (userID === '' && screenName !== '') {
        alert('Your user id are currently empty. The value you will be taken is your user identification');
        document.getElementById("takedvalue").value = screenName;
    }

    if (userID !== '' && screenName !== '') {
        document.getElementById("mainbtn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("backbtn").style.display = "initial";
        document.getElementById("choosescreenName").style.display = "initial";
        document.getElementById("chooseuserID").style.display = "initial";
    }
}

//Reset Form
$('.backbtn').click(function () {
    document.getElementById("mainbtn").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("backbtn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("choosescreenName").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("chooseuserID").style.display = "none";
});

//Choose First Input
$('.choosescreenName').click(function () {
    var screenName = document.getElementById("screenName").value;
    document.getElementById("takedvalue").value = screenName;
});

//Choose Second Input
$('.chooseuserID').click(function () {
    var userID = document.getElementById("userID").value;
    document.getElementById("takedvalue").value = userID;
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <form action="POST">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="screenName">Screen name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Screen Name" class="form-control " autocomplete="off" name="screenName" id="screenName" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userID">User ID</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="User ID" class="form-control user" autocomplete="off" name="userID" id="userID" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="mainbtn" onclick="verify();">SUBMIT</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary backbtn" id="backbtn" style="display:none;">BACK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary choosescreenName" id="choosescreenName" style="display:none;">CHOOSE SCREEN NAME</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary chooseuserID" id="chooseuserID" style="display:none;">CHOOSE USER ID</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <hr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userID">Value</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Taken Value" class="form-control" id="takedvalue" readonly />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```